# How to pass Information to frame's current page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm Not good at English, Thanks in advance.

I have problem that i just cant figure out right now. I am trying to develop a UWP and im stuck implementing this functionality.

I have a **Header**([Navigation view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview)) in NavPage, such as this.

[image]

As you know, The Header and The Frame in one page, **frame load a View**, When I click "Up" or other button(appbarButton), I want **pass a Info** to Frame's **current page(is MainPage)**.

At frist, I want invoking a current page method by appBarbutton, need static.**No**

then, I want pass a info to that page, and handle it in `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)`

**here is problem.**
this is code:

```
private void BackHome(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "*BackHome");
    }

    private void BackUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "*BackUp");

    }
```

I try two buttons.

But...when I click this appbar button,it is work, **info pass success**, but because Navigate() method, **the frame's current page is reload**, Parameters passed before useless

How pass info and **don't** reload?

any ideas? thanks every body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Navigate*** might actually not be the best suited method to call since what it actually does is telling your frame to read the content of the specified Page, something that you only want to do when your specified page is different from the one you're currently in.

**Edit 1.** 
Do you really need to pass information to the page for the situations where you're going to keep using the same content as your frame? If not, and just in order to stop the reloading for those situations, just check if you are actually calling the Navigate method to another page.

```
if(ContentFrame.SourcePageType != typeof(MainPage))
    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "*BackUp");
```

Comment: The page have Navigation view is "NavPage" , Sorry I have a mistake to write it is MainPage, and I correct. NavPage have a frame, MainPage is Frame's target page. when I invoke  `ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "*BackUp");` again, it also reload, I'm sure is not different specified page

Comment: Does this new edit help you? I am afraid, i might be not understanding exactly what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for your help.I want pass information to the page, When the frame's current page
is MainPage, I invoke `ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "*BackUp");`, I just want pass info only, not change Page. but it reload.

Comment: If you want to reuse the same page instance you should set the MainPage NavigationCacheMode property to Required and therefore you will actually reuse the same Page instance.

Comment: Great! Glad i could help! :)